# How to Form Tables Correctly When HTML Template Components are Separated?

Tags: lit

When building tables in Lit, sometimes I need to generate different parts of a table in different parts of the code. But when I put everything together, the table does not look the same as if it were declared all in one place.

See [this playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0cj5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCByb3dzcGFuPTI-MDwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQ-MTwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQ-MjwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgPC90YWJsZT5cbiAgICAgIGA7XG4gICAgXG4gICAgICBjb25zdCBoYWxmVGFibGUxID0gaHRtbGBcbiAgICAgICAgICA8dGFibGU-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0cj5cbiAgICAgIGA7XG4gICAgICBjb25zdCBoYWxmVGFibGUyID0gaHRtbGBcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCByb3dzcGFuPTI-MDwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQ-MTwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQ-MjwvdGQ-XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-XG4gICAgICAgICAgPC90YWJsZT5cbiAgICAgIGA7XG4gICAgXG4gICAgICB0YWJsZXMucHVzaCh0YWJsZTEpO1xuICAgICAgdGFibGVzLnB1c2goaHRtbGA8YnI-YCk7XG4gICAgICB0YWJsZXMucHVzaChoYWxmVGFibGUxKTtcbiAgICAgIHRhYmxlcy5wdXNoKGhhbGZUYWJsZTIpO1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICByZXR1cm4gdGFibGVzO1xuICB9XG5cbiAgcmVuZGVyKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiB0aGlzLmdlbmVyYXRlVGFibGVzKCk7XG4gIH1cbn1cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-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) for an example of the same table that's assembled two different ways. Is there any way I can make the "two halves" table look the same as the first, while still creating the elements in separate html`` blocks?

I tried creating a table in two different ways (see playground), I expected it to be the same resulting table in both instances. What actually happened is that they looked different, and I want to know why/how to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lit does not do string concatenation and each `html` tag function results in a cached Template element which can be efficiently rendered. This means that each of your html tags get implicitly closed by the browser's HTML parser.

E.g.: `` html`<table>...` `` is parsed by the browser into: `` html`<table>...</table>` ``. From lit.dev documentation on "Well-formed HTML": https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#well-formed-html

> Lit templates must be well-formed HTML. The templates are parsed by the browser's built-in HTML parser before any values are interpolated. Follow these rules for well-formed templates:

> Templates should not contain unclosed elements—they will be closed by the HTML parser.

Therefore instead of the following structure:

```js
// Does not work correctly - do not copy this. For demonstration purposes.
const start = html`<table>`;
const content = html`content`;
const end = html`</table>`;

const result = [start, content, end];
return html`${result}`;

// This would render as: <table></table>content<table></table>
```

Consider the following structure instead where each html tag function is well formed HTML:

```js
const tableFrame = (content) => html`<table>${content}</table>`;
const content = html`content`;

// Pass the content template result into the table frame.
return tableFrame(content);
```

The following is your code from the playground example restructured in this way:

```html
<script type="module">
import {LitElement, html, css} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/core/lit-core.min.js";

class TableExample extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }`;
  
  generateTables() {
      const tables = [];
      const tableRow1 = html`
        <tr>
          <td rowspan=2>0</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>`;
      const tableRow2 = html`
        </tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>`;

      const table1 = html`
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td rowspan=2>0</td>
                  <td>1</td>
              </tr>
              </tr>
                  <td>2</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      `;
      const tableFrame = (content) => html`<table>${content}</table>`;
      
      // Full table
      tables.push(table1);
      tables.push(html`<br />`);
      
      // Use tableFrame with custom content.
      tables.push(tableFrame(html`<tr><td>Custom Content</td></tr>`));
      tables.push(html`<br />`);
      
      // Use tableFrame with the two rows defined earlier.
      tables.push(tableFrame([tableRow1, tableRow2]));

      return tables;
  }

  render() {
    return this.generateTables();
  }
}
customElements.define('table-example', TableExample)
</script>

<table-example></table-example>
```

As an additional reference the documentation on Templates: https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#templates